# Why would TextureIO not accept newTexture(BufferedImage, Boolean?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to create a new texture:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("firstImage.jpg"));
Texture t = TextureIO.newTexture(image,true);
```

But get

The method `newTexture(File, boolean)` in the type `TextureIO` is not applicable for the `arguments (BufferedImage, boolean)`.

I'm importing

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.TextureIO;
```

Which according to the Javadoc should read `newTexture(BufferedImage, Boolean)`

So what Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the thread is a bit old, but my answer may help someone else. In JOGL2 (contrary to JOGL1.1), you have to use AWTTextureIO for loading BufferedImages, i.e. `Texture t = AWTTextureIO.newTexture(profile, image,true);`, where `profile` is your current GLProfile.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I decided to throw the image straight into the newTexture.

My code looks like

`//BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));`

`Texture t = TextureIO.newTexture(new File("image.jpg"),true);`

Thanks to all who looked.

JC